# How Linkchecker works in AEM 6.2

Tags: aem

I am working on linkchecker and want to know that when AEM saves the URLs in /var/linkchecker and on what basis?

If i am opening a link,then it saves it,or it has a polling like it traverse the complete content and put it in /var/linkchecker.

Which java class help to store valid or invalid links in its storage directory?

Answer (score 3):

LinkChecker is based on an eventHandler for /content (and child) nodes on creates and updates. All content is parsed and links are validated against allowed protocols and (configurable) external site links.

**External Links**

All the validation is done asynchronously in the background and the HTML is updated based on verification results.

/var/linkchecker is the cache for external links. The results based on simple GET requests to external links in order to optimise the process. The HTTP 200/30x response means that the links are valid. AEM looks at this cache before requesting a validation of the external link in order to optimize the page processing. This also means that the link validation is **NOT** real time and the delay is proportional to the load on your server.

All the links that have been checked can be seen via the `/etc/linkchecker.html` screen where you can request for revalidation and refresh the status of the links.

You can configure the frequency of this background check via the `Day CQ Link Checker Service` configuration under /system/console/configMgr. The default interval is *5 seconds* (scheduler.period parameter).

Under the config manager /system/console/configMgr you will find a lot of other Day CQ Link * configurations that control this feature.

For example, `Day CQ Link Checker Transformer` contains config for all the elements that need to be transformed by the link checker.

Similarly `Day CQ Link Checker Info Storage Service` configures the link cache.

**Internal Links**

Internal links are ignored unless they used FQDN and external urls (which is not normally the case on author). The only exception is in a multi-tenant environment where page from one site links to another site and all the mapping information is stored in sling mappings.

Comment: can you clear it to me that if i want to validate all links in a page,irrespective of internal and external,can link checker help me in that.and i also want to know that if i create a page,it immediately cached or it takes some time.

Comment: Internal links are node references so there validation is responsibility of the respective component. LinkChecker is primarily for external links and it will ignore internal links as they are relative and lack protocol prefix. Link checking is asynchronous so it will check in background and you can see a report (or force a check) via /etc/linkchecker page on author.

Comment: Updated answer with more details.

Comment: I am getting 404 blank image for an external site image url. How can I use link checker to display a default missing image rather than blank no image.

Comment: Can you post it as a new question to get a better answer?